# cljs quick start failed to locate namespace

Tags: clojurescript

I tries to [quick start](https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start) `cljs`, but the similar [problem](https://clojureverse.org/t/quick-start-issue/4179) occurred.

`clojure 1.10.3 on linux openjdk 17.0.1`

project folder:

```
.
|_ deps.edn
|_ src
     |_ helloworld
                 |_ core.cljs
```

core.cljs:

```clj
(ns helloworld.core)
(println "helloworld")
```

deps.edn

```clj
{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.758"}}}
```

tried to quick start under the project folder but failed,

```
$ clj -M -m cljs.main -c helloworld.core

Unexpected error (IllegalArgumentException) compiling at (REPL:1).
Namespace helloworld.core does not exist.
```

@EDIT However, tried on [lein-cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild) successfully.

```
$ lein cljsbuild once
```

project.clj (instead of deps.edn):

```clj
(defproject helloworld "0.1.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.3"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.758"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.8"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:source-paths ["src"]}]})
```

@EDIT I had to reboot the machine then tried again by chance - it works now. but "why" remains mysterious.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this problem with the instructions given. But it worked for me (cljs compiled stuff and the REPL started). So there must be something different.  Have you pasted the content of your actual files and locations or the ones the tutorial expects from you?

Comment: On the contrary, lein-cljsbuild compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, it wants `src/hello_world/core.cljs` as the file and `hello-world.core` for the namespace but you have `helloworld.core` for the ns and say you have `src/helloworld/core.cljs` for the file (which ought to work). That's the only difference I can see from the tutorial.

In addition, the tutorial has `--repl` on the `clj` command to cause a (ClojureScript) REPL to be started after compiling `helloworld.core` (using your ns).

That all works as expected for me:

```
(! 600)-> tree .
.
|____deps.edn
|____src
| |____helloworld
| | |____core.cljs

(! 601)-> cat deps.edn 
{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.758"}}}

(! 602)-> cat src/helloworld/core.cljs 
(ns helloworld.core)
(println "helloworld")

(! 603)-> clj -M -m cljs.main -c helloworld.core -r
ClojureScript 1.10.758
cljs.user=> helloworld
```

(and a browser opens with the ClojureScript welcome page)

That was with Clojure CLI 1.10.3.1029 (the latest) but I also tested it with 1.10.1.561 to make sure recent changes haven't affected the behavior and it also worked as expected.

I would recommend checking that you have the correct Clojure CLI installed:

```
(! 605)-> clj -version
Clojure CLI version 1.10.3.1029

(! 606)-> clj -Sdescribe
{:version "1.10.3.1029"
 :config-files ["/usr/local/Cellar/clojure@1.10.3.1029/1.10.3.1029/deps.edn" "/Users/sean/.clojure/deps.edn" "deps.edn" ]
 :config-user "/Users/sean/.clojure/deps.edn"
 :config-project "deps.edn"
 :install-dir "/usr/local/Cellar/clojure@1.10.3.1029/1.10.3.1029"
 :config-dir "/Users/sean/.clojure"
 :cache-dir ".cpcache"
 :force false
 :repro false
 :main-aliases ""
 :repl-aliases ""}
```

(the installation instructions are here: https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started if have some rogue `clj` script instead of the official one)

I *suspect* you have a non-standard `clj` script installed that tried to just run `helloworld.core` as if it were a `.clj` file.

Comment: I followed the official guide verbatim to install clj 1.10.3.1029. Really weird. I had done the same with previous versions of clj/openjdk  and cljs quick start had worked flawlessly in the past if i recall correctly.

Comment: I also followed the official cljs quick start guide verbatim except I changed all hello-world/hello_world uniformly to helloworld to avoid confusion.